# How to call a column named "group" in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table in Snowflake with the following structure:

```
| id | group | subgroup |
_________________________ 
| 1  | verst | burg     |
| 2  | travel| plane    |
| 3  | rest  | bet      |
```

I need to call only the column "group", so I tried the following code:

```
select t2.group
from  table as t2
```

but the following error arises

`SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 7 unexpected 'group'. syntax error line 2 at position 0 unexpected 'from'.`

I have also tried using:

```
select group
from  table as t2

select "group"
from  table as t2
```

but I always get the same error.
I know I can call the whole table using * but the real table where I get this data from has many more columns and we want to display this data in a dashboard. Additionally, I am not the owner of the table since it is filled by a microservice, so I cannot change the column names and I can't modify the microservice process.
I would appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Don't use `group`.  It is a SQL key word.

Comment: I know it is a SQL word so that's why the query does not work, but I didn't create the table and it is not possible for me to change the name of the columns.

Comment: Try using double quotes, but you need to be sure that the case of the column name is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the table could not be created without double quotes, you need to know how it was created to know how to refer to the column. Which is to say it the create code was `CREATE TABLE awsome ("GrOuP" string);` there you will need to type "GrOuP"

There is also a session setting to ignore case in double quotes that might help.
see [QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS_IGNORE_CASE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html#controlling-case-using-the-quoted-identifiers-ignore-case-parameter)

But by default things are upper case, thus try `"GROUP"`

Comment: Thank you, writing group in upper case and between double-quotes worked perfectly. This is my new query :
select t."GROUP"
from table  as t

Answer (score 2):

Putting group in double quotes worked fine when I tried it:

```
create or replace temporary table foo ( "group" string );

insert into foo values ('Hello world.');

select "group" from foo;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I don't know If I completely understood it, but I think that you are assuming that I can create or modify the table where I get the data from, however that is not the case, that's why I am asking. I just edited the question to make that clear.

Comment: I don't think this answer is assuming you have control over the table.  He is just showing the steps that he took to test it and that it works.  Make sure you use the correct case for the column in the table and use double-quotes.  That should avoid the conflict with SQL reserved words.

Comment: This works well to when table name is called with a reserved word, just appending double quotes to the name such like `TEST_DB.TEST_SCHEMA."GROUP"`